# Introduction of SVG in a span breaks the left to right positioning of child elements

Tags: css, svg

I have this simple html

```
<span>
<span>Hello</span>
<span>World</span>
</span>
```

and it displays

> Hello World

but if I introduce a SVG element like so

```
<span>
<span>Hello</span>
<span><svg role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 128 128" enable-background="new 0 0 128 128" xml:space="preserve"><path id="heart-full" d="M124 20.4C111.5-7 73.7-4.8 64 19 54.3-4.9 16.5-7 4 20.4c-14.7 32.3 19.4 63 60 107.1C104.6 83.4 138.7 52.7 124 20.4z"/></svg></span>
<span>World</span>
</span>
```

the elements are no longer positioned left to right and instead are stacked vertically.

> Hello
>
> ♥
>
> World

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lot140g/2/

How can I preserve the left to right stacking of child elements?

Comment: simply give a width to the SVG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default an SVG will expand as much as it can to fit the available screen space unless a definite size is given.

If you give the SVG a width or height....it will adopt that size.

```css
svg {
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<span>
<span>Hello</span>
<span><svg role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 128 128" enable-background="new 0 0 128 128" xml:space="preserve"><path id="heart-full" d="M124 20.4C111.5-7 73.7-4.8 64 19 54.3-4.9 16.5-7 4 20.4c-14.7 32.3 19.4 63 60 107.1C104.6 83.4 138.7 52.7 124 20.4z"/></svg></span>
<span>World</span>
</span>
```